# JMS - Messages are arriving at MDB after huge time delay

Tags: java-8, jms, wildfly-10

Server: Wildfly 10.0

JDK: JAVA 8

In my application, one of a feature is hosted with JMS.

The application may receive 1500+ messages (not more than 5000) every day. MDB (with maxSession=15) listens to queue and process the messages. The average processing time of a message @ MDB is < 1 sec.

Issue:

Often we are facing a delay in message appearing at MDB to processes it. Sometimes message pushed to the queue are arrived at MDB after 2 hours of time delay, there is no exception or delay in pushing a message to the queue. So we are trying to understand what would be the reason behind this behavior.

Comment: Get a thread dump from the Wildfly server to see what your MDB threads are doing (if anything). Also, confirm the consumer-count on the queue is > 0 during the delay.

Comment: @JustinBertram confirm that consumer-count is 15, when the messages are stuck in queue

Comment: What do the thread dumps indicate?